# Ubuntu 18.04 - Add new user and initialize it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I'm creating a .sh bash script in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS where I need to create a new user using the "adduser" command:

```
sudo adduser newuser
```

After that, I need to perfomr other operations like add some files in the newuser's Desktop or Documents folders. The main problem is that, untill I don't reboot the system, the newuser haven't that folders so I need to create them manually

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/newuser/Desktop
sudo mkdir -p /home/newuser/Documents
sudo mkdir -p /home/newuser/.local/share/applications
```

I really don't like this solution. Is there a way to initialize that folders after a user creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `xdg-user-dirs-update` tool which generates all required user directories in the `$HOME` path.

Don't forget to do `su newuser` first.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I have another question. My script need to work for different languages selected by the user. For example, I have to be able to reach the Desktop folder even if it has another name. There's an environment variable linked to it?

Comment: @El_Merendero According to (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html):
`xdg-user-dirs-update is normally run automatically at the start of a user session to update the XDG user dirs according to the users locale.`

So it probably should use default user locale for the folder names.

Comment: @El_Merendero I misunderstood your question. Each user in Ubuntu has a special config file `.config/user-dirs.dirs`, which contains the vars for user directories. To access the desktop you can `source .config/user-dirs.dirs`, after that the full path to the Desktop folder is held in `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` environment variable. Take a look here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/user-dirs.dirs.5.html